# App crashes in lower versions of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout

I have created my iPhone app using X code 4.5 and used .xib as 4 inch retina display mode,i have checked "Auto layout" in many views(actually while beginning i was not aware about size issue and all), Now my project is almost over,its running fine with ios6,but when i run it on ios5 it crashes and also if i unchecked all "Auto layout" it crashes in ios6 too.

I am not getting an idea about auto layout,
How can make it OK?

Comment: If you want to run on iOS 5, don't use auto layout.  If you have crashes with it turned off, post details of the crash information so that people can understand the problem.

Comment: but now if i am not using autolayout it crashes in ios6

(what size should i use for xib-4 inch or 3.5 inch)?

Comment: You can specify iOS6 as your minimum version if you wish, and eliminate problems with iOS5.  That will cut off some potential customers, but it is technically a solution.

Comment: I repeat, "If you have crashes with it turned off, post details of the crash information so that people can understand the problem."

Comment: Also, you need to be prepared for devices with 3.5 or 4" displays. An iPhone 4 can run iOS6 just like an iPhone 5.  Don't assume that just because your target OS is iOS 6 that you'll also have a 4" screen.  Post the errors you're seeing, and we can help with solutions.

Comment: @JishilKP http://emclstcd.tk

Comment: @Axeva ,Phillip Mills  - Thanks guys :)
It is 11PM in India, My app and machine are in my office,will defenitly post the error details tommorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use auto layout for iOS 5.0 and below versions..Remove check mark for all xibs and try...